# Running commands.getstatusoutput not returning expected results from apache

Tags: python, apache, openstack, openstack-heat

I have this following code as get_status.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from cgi import escape
from flup.server.fcgi import WSGIServer
import commands
import subprocess

def do_get_status():
    cmd = """/usr/bin/heat --os-username admin --os-password admin --os-tenant-name admin --os-auth-url http://ipaddress:35357/v2.0/ stack-show demo_stack"""
    status, out = commands.getstatusoutput(cmd)
    return "<pre>" + str(out) + "</pre>"

def app(environ, start_response):

    # initialise and login to the website
    #test = testpost.cookie(target_url,username, password)
    qs = environ['QUERY_STRING']
    result = do_get_status()

    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type', 'text/html')])
    return result

WSGIServer(app).run()
```

but when I do http://myserver/cgi-bin/get_status.py the output I am getting is

```
Unable to establish connection to http://ipaddress:35357/v2.0/tokens
```

That python script is running in apache cgi-bin. It was perfectly working fine 2 days back but now it stopped working all of a sudden. 
If I take command and run it on command line I get the expected result. I even tried running same piece of code with python get_status.py and I get the expected results.
I am not able to understand what could be the prob.

Comment: Are u sure that a domain can be `http://openstackserver` but not `http://openstackserver.com`

Comment: By the way, I'm not sure whether the `.` in `v2.0` can be a part of URL. Have you tried to open the URL in browser and see whether is works well?

Comment: openstackserver is an IP address. 
As I mentioned it works fine from the command line. 
Yes I am able to open the url browser.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue @bana? I'm having the same problem. I am able to execute [Python-SwiftClient's get_auth](https://github.com/openstack/python-swiftclient/blob/master/swiftclient/client.py#L403) in a python shell but not within a Django app (powered by apache).

Comment: Yes, please disable selinux or you can finegrain adjust the selinux settings to allow external connection and cli commands execution from apache

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue myself.  The brute force way was to disable selinux.  Once I determined that selinux was the cause of the issue, I further resolved it by doing a more finegrain adjustment of the selinux settings to allow external connection and cli commands execution from apache (e.g. a root:  `setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1` as mentioned in [this unix stackexchange post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8854/how-do-i-configure-selinux-to-allow-outbound-connections-from-a-cgi-script)